# react front end sending https in clear text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, security, ssl, https

### TLDR;

- Requests say they are sending in https
- Payload is in clear text
- force_ssl = true
- Very lost

---

### Detailed

I am running a react front-end talking to a rails back end via URLs provided by js-routes. The problem is that my requests state they are sending over https but the payload is clear text. I have been working on locking down my server for the past week but cannot seem to overcome this last hurdle.

### Info

- Site is secured with a SSL cert (I have a green lock throughout)
- React form
- Rails back end
- Ruby 2.3.3
- Rails 4.2.6
- React 15
- valid Cert with 300+ days before expiration
- force_ssl config = true
- Running server in production mode

### js-routes config

```
JsRoutes.setup do |config|
    protocol = Rails.application.secrets.protocol
    config.default_url_options = {
        format: :json,
        trailing_slash: true,
        protocol: protocol,
    }
end
```

### Request

Notice the https for the request but the clear text payload.
[image]

Am I just flat out missing something here?

Comment: Is this not normal to see it in plaintext in the browser here? I just logged into my bank and can see my username and password in the inspected request also

Comment: @Tony that might be the answer and what I was thinking too. I was thinking after I posted it might have that there so you[devs] can see the payloads before it's encrypted and sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Tony mentioned his comment and I'd already started to think about that as well, I did some tests with Wireshark today sniffing the traffic. The data **is indeed encrypted** as expected.

Thanks.